# ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is not working on plain HTML

Tags: tomcat, el

I'm using tomcat 7.0. Now I am facing an issue that could not load the css and js file.  trying to add ${pageContext.request.contextPath} but does not work, also tried c:url tag, but getting syntax error in eclipse.

The structure of these files is:

WebContent
-content/css/lab3.css
html and js folder are under content folder as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>lab3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/content/html/lab3.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/lab3.css"  media="screen, projection">
```

Comment: Expressions like `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` cannot be used in a plain HTML file, they must be used inside a JSP file. I suggest you start by reading a few tutorials about Java servlets and JSP.

Comment: @DavidLevesque okay, so in the plain HTML file, how should i access the location?

Comment: You can use a relative path, e.g.: `href="../css/lab3.css"`

Answer (score 6):

[EL expressions `${}`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) doesn't run in a plain HTML file. It runs in [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) (and [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info)) files only. In your particular case, it'd be merely a matter of renaming `lab3.html` to `lab3.jsp`, or adding the following JSP servlet mapping to `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> <!-- This is the default servlet name of Tomcat's own JSP servlet. To be sure, look in Tomcat's own web.xml for the exact name. -->
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which will tell Tomcat to treat all `.html` files as if they are JSP files, with the consequence that EL will instantly work as well in `.html` files.

If none of the above is an acceptable solution, then you'd need to fall back to logical thinking and properly understanding and using relative paths. Like as in local disk file systems, the `../` brings you one folder up in URLs. Provided that the HTML file is in `/content/html/lab3.html` and the CSS file is in `/content/css/lab3.css`, then the following should do:

```html
<link ... href="../css/lab3.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use ${request.contextPath} instead of ${pageContext.request.contextPath}